# Making an @ApplicationScoped JSF managed bean serializable a bad practice?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, scope

We keep getting the followng exception in our JSF-based Java web application and Googling about it suggests it could be caused by an application scoped jsf managed bean being serializable.

```
 java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1509)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:998)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:446)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4631)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4882)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1359)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1330)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:788)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:408)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:416)
```

The managed bean in question is injected to session scoped beans in some cases using the @ManagedProperty annotation.

Is this a bad practice, or is it something else that I don't get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because JSF managed bean facility does not integrate with Java serialization. If aBean depends on anotherBean, the instance of anotherBean is injected into aBean. Since serializing an object also serializes its fields, anotherBean will be serialized as well, which is at best a waste of memory, and at worst very hard to implement (because it may have dependencies that are not serializable ...).

A decent dependency injection container such as CDI or Spring will solve that problem by injecting a serializable proxy delegating to the current anotherBean into aBean. That is one reason why one should keep backing beans in a different DI container. (It is quite easy to use CDI or Spring-managed beans in JSF).

Edit: My sympathies for being locked in Java EE 5. In this case, you might:

1. Not keep the reference to an application-scoped bean as dependency, but look it up by name whenever you need it.
2. Inject a serializable proxy of your application-scoped bean (or make the application-scoped bean itself serializable). This will involve hooking into the serialization mechanism to serialize the bean by name, and reconstruct it upon deserialization by lookup.
3. Split your beans in two: One object for the dependencies (request-scoped), another object for the state (session-scoped). Personally I find this cumbersome and prohibitive for meaningful encapsulation of backing beans, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: The project is Java EE 5 (CDI unsupported)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... to my understanding, a `@ApplicationScoped` managed bean will live as long as the application is the deployed. In other words, I think you don't need to store and restore the bean when needed. It should always be there.

Instead of injecting the `@ApplicationScoped` bean as a `@ManagedProperty` of the `@SessionScoped` bean, why don't you try inject it into a `@RequestScoped` bean and then inject that `@RequestScoped` bean into your `@SessionScoped` bean. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but RequestScoped bean would be dead by the time http request / response cycle is over, so it doesn't make sense to me to inject a lower scoped bean into a higher one.

Comment: @fledglingCoder As meriton mentioned above, if you inject the `@ApplicationScoped` as a property into your `Serializable` bean, your `@ApplicationScoped` bean will always get serialized which resulted in your exception. Unless you switch to use CDI bean, you should do what I suggest and access what you need from the `@RequestScoped` bean.

Comment: thank you, but your suggestion is not applicable because the project is Java EE 5 (CDI not possible) the property to be injected is in an ApplicationScoped Bean, where it will be injected to is (and has to be) a SessionScoped bean, I removed the Serializable implementation of the Application Scoped bean and will see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade` is Tomcat's implementation of `HttpSession`. This exception thus suggests that you've in one of your view/session scoped managed beans the following property:

```
private HttpSession session;
```

This is completely wrong. You should never do that. The same story applies to `FacesContext`, `ExternalContext` and all of its artifacts. They should never be declared as a property of a managed bean, but always be declared in the thread local scope (i.e. inside the very same method block as where you need them).